# Intercept pinned SSL connection with private key

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, certificate-pinning

Can I intercept https traffic that uses certificate pinning using fiddler if I have the private key of the cert?

I am trying to intercept traffic between our mobile apps and API, and the mobile apps are using certificate pinning.

If I have the certificate and the private key from the web server, can I install it locally and use it to decrypt the traffic?

Seems like I should be able to.

Comment: How about this: http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/certinstall.html#using-a-custom-certificate

Answer (score 4):

Yes, generally speaking.

The comments have linked you correctly to the [mitm proxy documentation](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/certinstall.html#using-a-custom-certificate) for that feature already.

If that however is a feature of fiddler I do not know. If it's not in the documentation, go for MITM proxy instead:)

This, by the way, is independent of you using certificate pinning; this would work fine without a pinned certificate as well.

Whenever you have the private key, you can MITM.